# Form is not working

Tags: javascript, html

JSS

```
function kategori(dropdown) { 
  var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
  if (value == 'emlak'){
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'emlak'){
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "none";
  }if(value == 'vasita'){
    document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "block";  
  }else if(value != 'vasita'){
    document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "none";
  }if(value == 'alisveris'){
    document.getElementById("alisveris").style.display = "block";  
  }else if(value != 'alisveris'){
    document.getElementById("alisveris").style.display = "none";
  }if(value == 'is_makineleri_sanayi'){
    document.getElementById("is_makineleri_sanayi").style.display = "block";  
  }else if(value != 'is_makineleri_sanayi'){
    document.getElementById("is_makineleri_sanayi").style.display = "none";
  }if(value == 'hizmet'){
    document.getElementById("hizmet").style.display = "block";  
  }else if(value != 'hizmet'){
    document.getElementById("hizmet").style.display = "none";
  }if(value == 'kariyer'){
    document.getElementById("kariyer").style.display = "block";  
  }else if(value != 'kariyer'){
    document.getElementById("kariyer").style.display = "none";
  }if(value == 'hayvanlar_alemi'){
    document.getElementById("hayvanlar_alemi").style.display = "block";  
  }else if(value != 'hayvanlar_alemi'){
    document.getElementById("hayvanlar_alemi").style.display = "none";
  }
}
function emlak(dropdown) { 
  var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == 'konut'){
    document.getElementById("konut").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'konut'){
    document.getElementById("konut").style.display = "none";
  }  if (value == 'isyeri'){
    document.getElementById("isyeri").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'isyeri'){
    document.getElementById("isyeri").style.display = "none";
  }  if (value == 'arsa'){
    document.getElementById("arsa").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'arsa'){
    document.getElementById("arsa").style.display = "none";
  }  if (value == 'projeler'){
    document.getElementById("projeler").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'projeler'){
    document.getElementById("projeler").style.display = "none";
  }  if (value == 'bina'){
    document.getElementById("bina").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'bina'){
    document.getElementById("bina").style.display = "none";
  }  if (value == 'devremulk'){
    document.getElementById("devremulk").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'devre_mulk'){
    document.getElementById("devremulk").style.display = "none";
  }  if (value == 'turistik_tesis'){
    document.getElementById("turistik_tesis").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'turistik_tesis'){
    document.getElementById("turistik_tesis").style.display = "none";
  }
}
function konut(dropdown) { 
  var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
      if (value == 'satilik'){
    document.getElementById("satilik").style.display = "block";
  }else if(value != 'satilik'){
    document.getElementById("satilik").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'kiralik'){
    document.getElementById("kiralik").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'kiralik'){
    document.getElementById("kiralik").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'gunluk_kiralik'){
    document.getElementById("gunluk_kiralik").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'gunluk_kiralik'){
    document.getElementById("gunluk_kiralik").style.display = "none";
  }
}
function satilik(dropdown) { 
  var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
      if (value == 'daire'){
    document.getElementById("daire").style.display = "block";
  }else if(value != 'daire'){
    document.getElementById("daire").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'residence'){
    document.getElementById("residence").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'residence'){
    document.getElementById("residence").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'mustakil_ev'){
    document.getElementById("mustakil_ev").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'mustakil_ev'){
    document.getElementById("mustakil_ev").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'villa'){
    document.getElementById("villa").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'villa'){
    document.getElementById("villa").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'ciftlik_evi'){
    document.getElementById("ciftlik_evi").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'ciftlik_evi'){
    document.getElementById("ciftlik_evi").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'kosk_konak'){
    document.getElementById("kosk_konak").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'kosk_konak'){
    document.getElementById("kosk_konak").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'yali'){
    document.getElementById("yali").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'yali'){
    document.getElementById("yali").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'yali_dairesi'){
    document.getElementById("yali_dairesi").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'yali_dairesi'){
    document.getElementById("yali_dairesi").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'yazlik'){
    document.getElementById("yazlik").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'yazlik'){
    document.getElementById("yazlik").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'prefabrik_ev'){
    document.getElementById("prefabrik_ev").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'prefabrik_ev'){
    document.getElementById("prefabrik_ev").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'kooperatif'){
    document.getElementById("kooperatif").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'kooperatif'){
    document.getElementById("kooperatif").style.display = "none";
  }
}
function kiralik(dropdown) { 
  var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
      if (value == 'daire'){
    document.getElementById("daire").style.display = "block";
  }else if(value != 'daire'){
    document.getElementById("daire").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'residence'){
    document.getElementById("residence").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'residence'){
    document.getElementById("residence").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'mustakil_ev'){
    document.getElementById("mustakil_ev").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'mustakil_ev'){
    document.getElementById("mustakil_ev").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'villa'){
    document.getElementById("villa").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'villa'){
    document.getElementById("villa").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'ciftlik_evi'){
    document.getElementById("ciftlik_evi").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'ciftlik_evi'){
    document.getElementById("ciftlik_evi").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'kosk_konak'){
    document.getElementById("kosk_konak").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'kosk_konak'){
    document.getElementById("kosk_konak").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'yali'){
    document.getElementById("yali").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'yali'){
    document.getElementById("yali").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'yali_dairesi'){
    document.getElementById("yali_dairesi").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'yali_dairesi'){
    document.getElementById("yali_dairesi").style.display = "none";
  }if (value == 'yazlik'){
    document.getElementById("yazlik").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'yazlik'){
    document.getElementById("yazlik").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="ilan_ver_adim2.php">
  <select  name="kategori" class="kategori_element" onChange="kategori(this);" size="2">
    <option value="emlak">Emlak</option>
    <option value="vasita">Vasıta</option>
    <option value="yedek_parca_aksesuar_donanim_tuning" title="Yedek Parça, Aksesuar, Donanım & Tuning">Yedek Parça, Aksesuar, Donanım & Tuning</option>
    <option value="alisveris">Alışveriş</option>
    <option value="is_makineleri_sanayi" title="İş Makineleri & Sanayi">İş Makineleri & Sanayi</option>
    <option value="hizmet">Hizmet</option>
    <option value="kariyer">Kariyer</option>
    <option value="hayvanlar_alemi">Hayvanlar Alemi</option>
  </select>
  <select id="emlak" name="emlak" class="kategori_element" size="2" onChange="emlak(this);" style="display:none;">
    <option value="konut">Konut</option>
    <option value="isyeri">İşyeri</option>
    <option value="arsa">Arsa</option>
    <option value="projeler">Projeler</option>
    <option value="bina">Bina</option>
    <option value="devremülk">Devremülk</option>
    <option value="turistik tesis">Turistik Tesis</option>
  </select>
  <select class="kategori_element" id="vasita" onChange="" size="2" style="display:none;">
    <option value="">Otomobil</option>
    <option value="">Arazi, SUV & Pick-up</option>
    <option value="">Motosiklet</option>
    <option value="">Minivan, Van & Panelvan</option>
    <option value="">Ticari Araçlar</option>
    <option value="">Kiralık Araçlar</option>
    <option value="">Deniz Araçları</option>
    <option value="">Hasarlı Araçlar</option>
    <option value="">Klasik Araçlar</option>
    <option value="">Modifiye Araçlar</option>
    <option value="">Hava Araçları</option>
    <option value="">ATV</option>
    <option value="">UTV</option>
    <option value="">Engelli Plakalı Araçlar</option>
    <option value="">Karavan</option>
    <option value="">Elektrikli Araçlar</option>
  </select>
  <select class="kategori_element" id="alisveris" onChange="" size="2" style="display:none;">
    <option value="">Bilgisayar</option>
    <option value="">Cep Telefonu</option>
    <option value="">Fotoğraf & Kamera</option>
    <option value="">Ev & Dekorasyon</option>
    <option value="">Ev Elektroniği</option>
    <option value="">Elektronik</option>
    <option value="">Giyim & Aksesuar</option>
    <option value="">Güzellik & Kozmetik</option>
    <option value="">Bahçe & Yapı Market</option>
    <option value="">Bebek</option>
    <option value="">El İşi & Sanat</option>
    <option value="">Hobi & Oyuncak</option>
    <option value="">Kitap, Dergi & Film</option>
    <option value="">Koleksiyon</option>
    <option value="">Müzik</option>
    <option value="">Oyun & Konsol</option>
    <option value="">Saat</option>
    <option value="">Spor</option>
    <option value="">Takı, Mücevher & Altın</option>
    <option value="">Antika</option>
    <option value="">Medikal Ürünler</option>
    <option value="">Ofis Malzemeleri</option>
    <option value="">Yiyecek & İçecek</option>
    <option value="">Diğer Her Şey</option>
  </select>
  <select class="kategori_element" id="is_makineleri_sanayi" onChange="" size="2" style="display:none;">
    <option value="">İş Makinesi</option>
    <option value="">Sanayi</option>
    <option value="">Elektrik & Enerji</option>
  </select>
  <select class="kategori_element" id="hizmet" onChange="" size="2" style="display:none;">
    <option value="">Vasıta Hizmetleri</option>
    <option value="">Ev Tadilat & Dekorasyon</option>
    <option value="">Bebek ve Çocuk</option>
    <option value="">Nakliye</option>
    <option value="">Kiralık Ürünler</option>
    <option value="">Kurs & Dershaneler</option>
    <option value="">Özel Ders Verenler</option>
    <option value="">Baskı Hizmetleri</option>
    <option value="">Bayilik Verenler & Franchise</option>
    <option value="">Cenaze İşleri</option>
    <option value="">Danışmanlık</option>
    <option value="">Dış Ticaret & Gümrük</option>
    <option value="">Düğün & Organizasyon</option>
    <option value="">El Sanatları</option>
    <option value="">Evcil Hayvanlar</option>
    <option value="">Giyim & Tekstil</option>
    <option value="">Güzellik Merkezleri</option>
    <option value="">Hurda & Atık</option>
    <option value="">Öğrenci Yurdu</option>
    <option value="">Reklam & Tanıtım</option>
    <option value="">Sağlık & Spor</option>
    <option value="">Sigortacılık & Finans</option>
    <option value="">Tamir, Teknik Servis</option>
    <option value="">Taşeron Hizmetleri</option>
    <option value="">Temizlik & İlaçlama</option>
    <option value="">Tercümanlık & Çeviri</option>
    <option value="">Turizm Hizmetleri</option>
    <option value="">Yazılım & Bilgi İşlem</option>
    <option value="">Yemek ve Gıda</option>
  </select>
  <select class="kategori_element" id="kariyer" onChange="" size="2" style="display:none;">
    <option value="">Bankacılık</option>
    <option value="">Dönemsel İşler</option>
    <option value="">Eğitim</option>
    <option value="">Güzellik & Bakım</option>
    <option value="">Hukuk</option>
    <option value="">IT ve Yazılım Geliştirme</option>
    <option value="">İnsan Kaynakları</option>
    <option value="">İnşaat ve Yapı</option>
    <option value="">İşletme ve Stratejik Yönetim</option>
    <option value="">Koruma ve Güvenlik</option>
    <option value="">Kültür, Sanat ve Eğlence</option>
    <option value="">Lojistik ve Taşıma</option>
    <option value="">Muhasebe / Finans</option>
    <option value="">Mühendislik</option>
    <option value="">Müşteri Hizmetleri</option>
    <option value="">Ofis Yönetimi ve İdari İşler</option>
    <option value="">Pazarlama ve Ürün Yönetimi</option>
    <option value="">Restoran ve Konaklama</option>
    <option value="">Sağlık</option>
    <option value="">Satış</option>
    <option value="">Tamir ve Bakım</option>
    <option value="">Tasarım / Yaratıcılık</option>
    <option value="">Üretim ve İmalat</option>
    <option value="">Yetiştirme Hayvancılık</option>
  </select>
  <select class="kategori_element" id="hayvanlar_alemi" onChange="" size="2" style="display:none;">
    <option value="">Evcil Hayvanlar</option>
    <option value="">Akvaryum Balıkları</option>
    <option value="">Aksesuarlar</option>
    <option value="">Yem ve Mama</option>
    <option value="">Kümes Hayvanları</option>
    <option value="">Büyükbaş Hayvanlar</option>
    <option value="">Küçükbaş Hayvanlar</option>
    <option value="">Deniz Canlıları</option>
    <option value="">Sürüngenler</option>
    <option value="">Böcekler</option>
    <option value="">Bakım</option>
  </select>
  <select id="konut" class="kategori_element" size="2" onChange="konut(this);" style="display:none;">
    <option value="satilik">Satılık</option>
    <option value="kiralik">Kiralık</option>
    <option value="gunluk_kiralik">Günlük Kiralık</option>
  </select>
  <select id="satilik" class="kategori_element" size="2" onChange="satilik(this);" style="display:none;">
    <option value="daire">Daire</option>
    <option value="residence">Residence</option>
    <option value="mustakil_ev">Müstakil Ev</option>
    <option value="villa">Villa</option>
    <option value="ciftlik_evi">Çiftlik Evi</option>
    <option value="kosk_konak">Köşk &amp; Konak</option>
    <option value="yali">Yalı</option>
    <option value="yali_dairesi">Yalı Dairesi</option>
    <option value="yazlik">Yazlık</option>
    <option value="prefabrik_ev">Prefabrik Ev</option>
    <option value="kooperatif">Kooperatif</option>
    <button type="submit">İlan Ver</button>
  </select>
</form>
```

My form is not working when i add form tag to start and to end i want create a category selector for e-trade webpage. i dont know which one is wrong java script or html please help.
why i cant type my message it want soo much detail.

Comment: Off: Well, this is some odd dry coding... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? What errors do you get?

Comment: I....I honestly don't know where to start looking. What is 'not working' about it? We know it's not working, that's why your here. What **should** it be doing that it isn't doing? I mean, from a glance only 2 of your bazillion selects have a name attribute, and the majority of your options don't actually have a value, I'd suggest starting there.

Comment: Re-engineering. That's the way to go. I feel sorry for the developers whom will maintain this piece of code.

Comment: To get even start with this, you need to rename your functions, they are shadowed by the names/ids of the `select` elements. And please, rewrite your code using for example system suggested by Dolondro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't obvious (as you haven't really paired down your code to anything that we can use).

Here's three things that potentially could be causing your issues:

1. You lack name attributes to a lot of your elements. If the form successfully submits, then if an element doesn't have a name attribute, you won't actually get any data appearing.
2. A lot of your options have value="". This means that if you successfully send that data in a POST request, then *whatever* is selected in that option box will only return "". This will be of absolutely 0 help to anyone.
3. Not technically an issue that is likely to be causing your issues, but you need to get  your head around loops. As it stands, the vast majority of your code is just you repeating yourself. An example for you to look at that would replace your kategori javascript function:

**Code:**

```
function kategori(dropdown) { 
  var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value,
      list = ["emlak", "vasita", "alisveris", "is_makineleri_sanayi", "hizmet", "kariyer", "hayvanlar_alemi"];

  for (var x=0; x<list.length; x++){
    document.getElementById(list[x]).style.display = (list[x]==value?"block":"none");
  }
}
```